# How to add second row to ToolBarContent in MudTable

Tags: c#, css, html-table, mudblazor

I'm currently trying to add a second row with MudChipSet for my Filter in ToolBarContent of MudTable, but I'm facing problems to implement it so that the first row doesn't get pushed away.
Here is my current code, any suggestions how to add a second row with some buttons? It's main purpose is to enable/disable Filter functions.

```
<MudGrid Spacing="3" Justify="Justify.Center">
    <MudItem>
        <MudPaper>
            <MudTable Items="@_crashInformations" MultiSelection="true" Filter="new Func<CrashInformation,bool>(FilterFunc1)" @bind-SelectedItems="_selectedItems"
                  Hover="true" Striped="true" Dense="true">
                <ToolBarContent>
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Test</MudText>
                    <MudSpacer />
                    <MudTextField @bind-Value="_searchString" Placeholder="Search" Immediate="true" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0" />
                </ToolBarContent>
                <HeaderContent>
                    <MudTh>Analyse</MudTh>
                    <MudTh>Bearbeiten</MudTh>
                    <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
                    <MudTh>Crashpointer</MudTh>
                    <MudTh>Date</MudTh>
                    <MudTh>Affected Version</MudTh>
                    <MudTh>State</MudTh>
                    <MudTh>Assignee</MudTh>
                    <MudTh>Fixed Version</MudTh>
                    <MudTh>Fixed Date</MudTh>
                    <MudTh>Description</MudTh>
                </HeaderContent>
```

Here is how it looks right now:
[image: current]

In the end it should look something like that:
[image: wish to be]

Comment: Hi . What do you mean by "implement it so that the first Row doesn't get pushed away"? The text "Test" and the search bar are on the same line.

Comment: I mean, that when I try to add a second row under the Text "test" and the Searchbar, which still is above the Table Headers, like I tried to show in my last Picture (not so good added with Photoshop), basically I wanna have the opportunity for the user to use the searchbar without typing in the searchbar, but by sole press of the Mudchip. Now do I not want to add it on the same level like the Text and the Searchbar, but below it, hope it's understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToolBarContent` has flexbox layout. To get two rows enable wrapping of flex items, and push `MudChipSet` to the separate line by telling it to occupy the full width of the flexbox. You also need to reset the `height` of flexbox, because now it is set to some nondefault value.

```
<style>
  .mud-table-toolbar              { flex-wrap: wrap;
                                    height: inherit; }
  .mud-table-toolbar .mud-chipset { flex-basis: 100%; }
</style>
```

Here is the code of `ToolBarContent`:

```
<ToolBarContent>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Test</MudText>
    <MudSpacer />
    <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString1" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start"
                  AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0" />
    <MudChipSet MultiSelection Filter>
        <MudChip Text="Chip1" />
        <MudChip Text="Chip2" />
        <MudChip Text="Chip3" />
    </MudChipSet>
</ToolBarContent>
```